# Visual Studio Code: Is it possible to add a task to tasks.json that reruns the previous task?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to add a task to my VS Code tasks.json file that can rerun the last task that I ran.

I know there is a command `Rerun Last Task` that I can use when I press `F1` to `Show All Commands`. However, not every developer knows about typing `F1` to show all commands, but they know about `F7` for build tasks. That's why I want to add something to our baseline tasks.json.

Is there a way to somehow call the `Rerun Last Task` command in tasks.json? Or maybe there is a variable that has the last task run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "label": "rerun last command",
  "command": "${command:workbench.action.tasks.reRunTask}",
  "type": "shell",
  "problemMatcher": [],
},
```

That task will rerun the last task.  You see you can make any command into a variable for use within launch.json or tasks.json with the form:

`${command:some command ID here}`

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables

That creates a "command variable" which can be used as an argument or as a command.